# WP7 how to handle Flick and DragDelta event

Tags: windows-phone-7, drag, gesture

I want to make a sliding panel in Windows Phone 7, like the status panel in Android, that supports Tap, Drag and Flick gesture.

I'm using toolkit `GestureListener` for my `StackPanel`. It works for the `Tap` and `DragDelta` event. However when the user flicks, both `DragDelta` and `Flick` event is raised, which is hard for me to detect if user wants to drag or flick.

How can I handle these  two events ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `DragCompleted` event, there is `VerticalVelocity` information that can acts as a `Flick` detection. See [windowsphonegeek](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-GestureService-in-depth--key-concepts-and-API) for more information

> **VerticalVelocity**
>
> The final vertical (Y) velocity of the drag, if the drag was inertial.

```
public double VerticalVelocity { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://multitouch.codeplex.com/

The following link has both the tool kit and all the relevant details you may require to use the Tap, Drag features.

Comment: is it different from default silverlight toolkit for WP ?

Comment: It is quite different. As you had mentioned, the default toolkit is quite hard to use. I had previously created a game which required the App to differentiate between different touch gestures. This toolkit helped.

Comment: it seems that the object need to be in the Canvas, and I use Storyboard to translate, so multitouch seems to overkill and not suit my need